# Angular: method to set custom error and edit fields

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

In a form, whenever there is a error, clearing the text fields and setting the errors as below

```
switch(result){
    case "SUCCESS":
        // success case
    case "ERROR1":
            this.Form.controls.text1.setValue('');
            this.Form.controls.text2.setValue('');
            this.Form.controls.text1.setErrors({ 'error1': true });
            break;
    case "ERROR2":
            this.Form.controls.text1.setValue('');
            this.Form.controls.text2.setValue('');
            this.Form.controls.text1.setErrors({ 'error2': true });
            break;
    case "ERROR3":
            this.Form.controls.text1.setValue('');
            this.Form.controls.text2.setValue('');
            this.Form.controls.text1.setErrors({ 'error3': true });
            break;
}
```

To avoid repeated lines, a method was written as below

```
setError(error : string){
    this.Form.controls.text1.setValue('');
    this.Form.controls.text2.setValue('');
    this.Form.controls.text1.setErrors({ error: true });
}

switch(result){

    case "SUCCESS":
        // success case
    case "ERROR1":
            setError('error1');
            break;
    case "ERROR2":
            setError('error2');
            break;
    case "ERROR3":
            setError('error3');
            break;
}
```

Fields are getting clear, but not able to set error. Any suggestions how to set particular error as true.

Comment: I could be wrong here but could you try calling `updateValueAndValidity()` after you set the error?

Comment: Looks like you have a typo. You reference `this.Form` when setting the value and `this.form` when setting the errors.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what i have inferred was, you are trying to clear the fields and set the error to your formControls.

To set an error to a field,

```
this.Form.get('controlName').setErrors({notUnique: true});
```

To reset all the field in your form,

```
this.Form.reset();
```

Also, If you want to validate your form with custom validators refer the below link:
https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/

Comment: Need to pass value to error:string
in - this.Form.controls.text1.setErrors({ error: true });

Comment: check this link - [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formcontrols-seterror]. To setErrors function you can pass a json object with any key and value.